# Can't commit multiple changes made offline

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have been working offline for a couple of days so I didn't have access to my code repository. In order to maintain revisions I created several backups of the versiones that I've created offline and I planned to commit all of them once I go online.
However, after I have committed the first one of my offline versions (the oldest) I found myself unable to commit the rest cause when I attempt to commit any of my offline versions the svn client says that the resource is out of date, which is technically correct because the modified date of the committed offline version (the older one) is today while those other offline versions were created say yesterday.

Do I have to manually merge the versions?

I actually tried updating the working copy and overwriting its files with my offline newer ones. Then I resolved conflicts as "mine" and committed tha changes. But I got stuck when the svn refused to add a new directory upon the next update to my proj cause it has been already created.

Comment: You can use the "svn ci filename1 filename2 ..." syntax instead of an "svn commit" to commit multiple files while leaving out the directory that is already added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess: you copied all the `.svn` folders and you are trying to overwrite the up-to-date ones in your working copy with the outdated archived  ones.

If that's the case, you have to remove all the `.svn` folders *in your backup* before copying source files into your working copies.

Comment: Oops.. that was very lame of me. Thank you so much!